# How do I configure the driver for eth0 so I can use a kickstart file over the network?

Tags: rhel, kickstart, oracle-linux, installer-anaconda

I am trying to use a kickstart file hosted over the network to install Oracle Linux 5.8 (equivalent to RHEL 5.8 I believe). I am using the following at the boot prompt:

```
linux ks=http://1.2.3.4/my.ks ksdevice=eth0 ip=dhcp
```

The problem is that at this point, eth0 does not seem to be configured with a driver and I am prompted to select one. Having looked at the various Anaconda docs online, I can't see anything that would let me configure the driver for eth0 from the boot prompt, so that I am not prompted for one afterwards.

Does anyone know of a way to set-up eth0 with a driver from the boot prompt?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `dd` option to kickstart and provide the driver disk locally. See https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-startinginstall.html for the `dd` option, and https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-options.html for the `driverdisk` directive inside the kickstart file (you need both, I'm pretty sure).